# How to do search/replace in Aptana JavaScript editor for selection only?

Tags: replace, aptana, aptana3

I was trying to replace single to double quotes for single declaration, I've selected the block, pressed CTRL+F, a nice search&replace panel shown up.

OK, I have Replace, Replace All. OK, I have also scope: Current file, Open files, Enclosing project, Workspace.

But where is **selection**?

How to replace the text in **selection only**?

I'm using Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.1.201306062137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Window -> Preferences

Aptana Studio -> Find Bar -> "Show Eclipse search dialog on 2nd Ctrl + F"

Then it's necessary to press CTRL+F 2 times, and the "clasical" search/replace dialog is displayed.